# How to upload the files to google drive only once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Using this code, I am uploading the files to google drive successfully. But each time when I run this code, it uploads the same files to google drive again. What I want is to stop this repetition of uploading the data and just upload the newly created file.

```
import os
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

http = httplib2.Http()
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('thermal-highway.json', SCOPES)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=credentials.authorize(http))

def upload_folders(name, folder_id):
    file_metadata = {
        'name': name,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents': folder_id
    }
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
    print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
  
def list_files(path):
    folderId = ['62bewyZXHy9JfSLG9N96U1e548luuCAWR']
    for files in os.listdir(path):
        d = os.path.join(path, files)
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            upload_folders(files, folderId)

path = "/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/"
list_files(path)
```

Comment: You could get a list of existing files from a folder in google drive. Then only upload file to that folder if its name is not in list. Its better than checking existence of every file in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) which creates a new file each time.  If you want to update an existing file then you should be using [file.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

```
# File's new content.
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(
        new_filename, mimetype=new_mime_type, resumable=True)

    # Send the request to the API.
    updated_file = service.files().update(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=file,
        media_body=media_body).execute()
```